# "Cannot GET /" and "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" error on nodejs app

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to run my nodejs application but i getting this error on my web browser and console;
`Cannot GET /` and `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJiPi.png)

This is my `server.js` file;

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const logger = require('morgan')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const config = require('./api/utils/config')
const db = require('./api/utils/db')
const v1Routes = require('./routes/V1routes')

logger.token('date', () => {
  return new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "America/New_York" })
})
app.use(logger('[:date[]] :remote-addr ":method :url HTTP/:http-version" :status '))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '200mb' }))
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '200mb' }))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cors())

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
  next()
})

app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'))
app.use('/static', express.static('static'))

app.use('/api/v1', v1Routes)


db.getConnection()
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(config.port, async () => {
      console.log(`Server Started at http://${config.host}:${config.port}`)
    })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })

module.exports = app;
```

This is my .env file

```
APP_NAME=DTLive
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:GHlKvYv+hmpj0KR+73qH5APmQmZcjVARI0ABBCMcFIM=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost/admin/public/admin/login

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dt_live
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

JWT_SECRET=


IMAGE_PATH=http://localhost/admin/public/images/
API_URL=http://localhost/admin/api/
```

This is my config.js file

```
module.exports = (function () {
  let data = {
    IMAGE_BASE_PATH: "http://localhost/admin/public/images/",
    BASE_PATH: "http://localhost/admin/public/",
    USER_BASE_PATH: "C:/xampp/htdocs/admin/public/images/",
    JWTSecretKey: "",
    default_auth_token: "jQfq4I2q6lv",
    refresh_token: "",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8080,
    androidAppVerision: "1.0.0",
    iosAppVerision: "1.0.0",
    mailerEmail: "",
    mailerPassword: "@",
    awsAccesskey: "",
    awsSecretkey: "",
    s3bucketName: "",
    s3uploadURL: "",
    buildingRadius: 50,
    paginationCount: 5,
    colorLogoLink: '',
    notificaionCount: 10,
    landlord_flag: 1,
    property_manager_flag: 2,
    attorney_flag: 3,
    process_server_flag: 4,
    admin_flag: 5,
    distanceRadius: 10,
    admin_user_type_for_chat_user: 5,
    budget_sms_username: "",
    budget_sms_user_id: "",
    budget_sms_handle: "",
    timeRegex: /^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)$/,
    dateRegex: /^(19|20|21|22)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/,
    language: [{ name: "en", value: "English" }, { name: "tr", value: "Turkish" }, { "name": "fa", "value": "Farsi" }, { "name": "ar", "value": "Arabic" }],

    auto_detect_code: "jQfq4I2q6lv",
    distanceMatrixAPI: "",
    adminPanelLink: ''
  }
  
    data.host = 'localhost'
    data.db = {
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      password: "",
      database: "dt_live"
    }
    data.forgotPasswordLinkPrefix = ``
    data.reset_password_link = ``
    data.privacy_policy_url = ``
    data.terms_and_conditions_url = ``
    data.paymentLink = ``
    data.iyzicoKey = ``
    data.iyzicoSecretKey = ``
    data.iyzicoURI = ``
 
  return data;
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a handler for `/`, so you're getting the response from express' default catch-all middleware, error-handler.

If you access a route your application handles (such as anything under `/api/v1`), you should get a response from your own code.

You could also, of course, add a route handler for `/`:

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.end('it works!');
});
```